# Delphi Checkbox grayed and checked

Tags: delphi, checkbox, datafield

I have been working with Delphi for about a month now so I'm relatively new.
I have a checkbox that greys out when I change the data field just want to know why that might be?

Comment: Well, when I try it doesn't grey out. You must be doing something differently, I just don't know what. Iow, how can we reproduce? Please read about [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @TomBrunberg Hi Tom, Not exactly sure how to tell you to reproduce the problem as the button has no functionality code. what I can tell you is that it is a TDBCheckBox and when my code is running I'm still able to check and uncheck the box and as soon as I uncheck it the grayed-out part goes away it as the check box. I copied the original checkbox and pasted it in the exact same aria changed the DataField and the grayed-out part goes away and it functions as a normal checkbox

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @TomBrunberg    object DBCheckBox1: TDBCheckBox
        Left = 161
        Top = 424
        Width = 20
        Height = 17
        DataField = 'Ignore Producer ID Allocation'
        DataSource = LookupDM.FarmDS
        TabOrder = 27
        ValueChecked = 'True'
        ValueUnchecked = 'False'
      end

Comment: Please don't add details in comments. Edit them into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your TDBCheckBox is grayed because the value of the datafield assigned to it does not match ValueChecked or ValueUnchecked properties.From [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBCheckBox.ValueChecked)

> If the contents of the field matches no string in either ValueChecked
>   or ValueUnchecked, the check box appears gray.

Comment: Thank you so mutch this actually helped as it was the Null value in my DB causing this to happen and I will bookmark that page you linked